# HashMap giving multiple values for a single key

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

```
    String inputString = myScan.nextLine();
    char[] inp = inputString.toCharArray();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> m1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    for (char i : inp) {
        if (m1.get(i) != null) {
            m1.put(i, m1.get(i) + 1);
        } else {
            m1.put(i, 0);
        }
        System.out.println(m1.get('a'));
    }
```

When aaabbbb is passed as input . I get 0
1
2
2
2
2
2 as output .Thats is one key is mapped to multiple values . Whereas I know HashMap does not store duplicate keys.Can anybody explain?

Comment: You can save a Collection as a value so you have many values for one key

Comment: The best way to figure this out (as is usually the case) is to step through it with your debugger, watching it run, inspecting your variables as you got. Using a debugger is a crucial part of learning to program, and programming.

Comment: Why do you think your `HashMap` is storing duplicate keys?  You are printing the single value of the key `'a'` multiple times.

Comment: Each value you put for a key replaces the previous one. It doesn't have multiple values at once.

Answer (score 1):

You're not mapping `'a'` to multiple values; you're mapping it to one value, the integer `2`.  On the line `m1.put(i, m1.get(i) + 1)` you are overwriting the value previously stored in `m1` for key `i`.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the amount of times `'a'` has been counted so far on each iteration of the loop. This is absolutely not what you wanted to achieve and the output is indeed correct since frequency for `'a'` is incremented by 1 for first 3 iterations and then stays at 2.

Then another error is that the first time you see a character you set its frequency to 0 while it should be set to 1.

Last but not least, Java8 is mature and should be used to simplify code. You could automatically partition frequences or at least use `HashMap.compute`:

```
for (char c : inp)
  m1.compute(c, (v, entry) -> entry == null ? 1 : entry + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't expose all the information to replicate your problem, but to me is clear that you are asigning differente values to the key "a" while your program runs, and that values are geting printed in standard output, that's all, there is nothing wrong with map storing multiple times the same key, in fact google multimaps do this trick.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the value of m1.get('a') 7 times - the and for three of this 7 times, you are updating the value starting from 0 (maybe you should start from 1). I suppose you want to count the different chars in a string. As it is, it works as expected.